# Unix programming in C for simple files

Tags: c, unix, file-io

I have to write a simple program to output 16 bytes of data to a file at 0 and 48th position and have come up with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int f = create("test.tmp",774);
    if(f>0)
    {
        write(f,"DEPARTMENT OF CS",16);
        lseek(f,48,SEEK_SET);
        write(f,"DEPARTMENT OF IS",16);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this? It tells me when I compile using `cc 7a.sh -ll` that:

> undefined to reference to 'create'

Comment: This is not C++, you're not even building it with a C++ compiler. It's straight C with POSIX functions. There's also no reason to be using `creat` instead of `open`, and your test of `f>0` is at best questionable, since `0` is a valid file descriptor that `open` _could_ in fact return if it were available. I also see no particular reason why you're resorting to POSIX-specific file I/O here instead of the standard C library functions.

Comment: `cc 7a.sh -ll`? This is a remarkably strange command with which to compile a C++ source file! It doesn't even look like C++ in the file.

Comment: 774 is definitely wrong. You probably meant 0774.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no function named `create`

It's named [creat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/creat.html)

Comment: @footy Right from the link: "RATIONALE - The creat() function is redundant. Its services are also provided by the open() function. It has been included primarily for historical purposes since many existing applications depend on it." Why are you using it in new code?

Comment: Ken Thompson was once asked what he would do differently if he were redesigning the UNIX system. His reply: "I'd spell creat with an e."

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ( "example.txt" , "w" );
  fputs ( "This is an apple." , pFile );
  fseek ( pFile , 9 , SEEK_SET );
  fputs ( " sam" , pFile );
  fclose ( pFile );
  return 0;
}
```

via http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/